# Cannot access GCP VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I've been trying to connect to a VM instance for the past couple of days now. Here's what I've tried:

- Trying to SSH into it returns `username@ipaddress: Permission denied (publickey).`
- Using the Google Cloud SDK returns this:

  ```
  No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-a] for instance: [instancename].

  Updating project ssh metadata...done.
  Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
  SFATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
  ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to theinstance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.
  ```
- Using the browser SSH [just gets stuck on "Transferring SSH keys to the VM."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhbN6.png)
- Using PuTTy also results in `No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

I checked the serial console and found this:

```
systemd-hostnamed.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No space left on device
```

I did recently resize the disk and did restart the VM, but this error still occurs.

Access to port 22 [is allowed in the firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQNRV.png). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi there! Take a look to [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) page. Try to follow Google's guide on how to troubleshoot SSH. Share with us if you are not able to access your VM despite following the guide; do not forget to add the steps you already performed.

Comment: Hello! I've read the troubleshooting page and tried enabling the guest environment, but after checking the serial console, all I see is "No space left on device". Oddly enough, I increased the boot disk size from 10 GB to 16 GB earlier today, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

After increasing the disk size you need to reboot the instance so the filesystem can be resized, just in this specific case because you already ran out of space.

If you have not already done so, create a snapshot of the VM's boot disk.

Try to restart the VM.

If you still can't access the VM, do the following:

Stop the VM:

`gcloud compute instances stop VM_NAME`

Replace VM_NAME with the name of your VM.

Increase the size the boot disk:

`gcloud compute disks resize BOOT_DISK_NAME --size DISK_SIZE`

Replace the following:

BOOT_DISK_NAME: the name of your VM's boot disk
DISK_SIZE: the new larger size, in gigabytes, for the boot disk

Start the VM:

`gcloud compute instances start VM_NAME`

Reattempt to SSH to the VM.

Comment: I already rebooted the instance right after resizing, yet this problem still occurs.

Comment: The edited version of your answer still doesn't help, as I also tried this before

Comment: The only option I can see so far is to attach the boot disk into a different instance and check the logs and confirm it is not a disk size issue but ssh issue.